# Java ASM4: super(ASM4);?

Tags: java, bytecode, java-bytecode-asm, bytecode-manipulation

Well I was reading the PDF tutorial/documentation/book(if you will) on the ASM4 Bytecode library. I was trying out the examples and learn as I went by, by reading, and actually typing out the code, executing, then learning from the output. I came across this part:

```
   public class ClassPrinter extends ClassVisitor {
      public ClassPrinter() {
      super(ASM4);
   }
```

Here is the link: `http://download.forge.objectweb.org/asm/asm4-guide.pdf`

I cant figure out what to pass in the super. My IDE wasn't very helpful either.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That is an ASM4 [API version constant](http://asm.ow2.org/asm40/javadoc/user/org/objectweb/asm/Opcodes.html#ASM4). Also see JavaDoc for [ClassVisitor(int)](http://asm.ow2.org/asm40/javadoc/user/org/objectweb/asm/ClassVisitor.html#ClassVisitor%28int%29) constructor.